# MapBox Android SDK API 2.2 - Polygon Click Listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, mapbox, mapbox-gl

As of today, MapBox's newest Android SDK library [here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/2.2.0/) (2.2) does not include a Polygon Click Listener.

Has anyone seen a custom Polygon Click Listener method for MapBox Android?  I would think that this is a commonly needed method for MapBox Android developers.

Comment: Good Question.  I realize this does not directly answer your question.  Here's an example that shows polygon click for mapbox gl js https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/  But I'd like to see an Android SDK version.  Can you add mapbox-gl as a tag.  Maybe the GL people will notice.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the mapbox team who directed me to this answer.  See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3720

An android sdk native Polygon Listener is not yet supported.  The issue talks about it.  Please comment in the issue to show your interest.

Many Thanks to Antonio at Mapbox for the information.